# Why storing Unicode Characters in char works?

Tags: c, unicode, char

I have a program I made to test I/O from a terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *input[100];
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s", input);
    return 0;

}
```

It works as it should with ASCII characters, but it also works with Unicode characters and emoji.

Why is this?

Comment: i think this line `char* input [100]` you mean `char input [100]`. There is a difference between  `char *` and  `char **’`

Comment: Pleae indent your code.

Comment: Besides the UB, it depends on *encoding*. For example a character in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding can be stored as one or more *bytes* (i.e. one or more `char`).

Comment: in c one char is just one byte, so a char array can actually store anything. a unicode char can just use mulitple of the classic chars. so if you dimension the array to 100 it might not be able to hold 100 unicode chars.

Comment: @KaiIskratsch: The definition of a "Unicode character" is a bit opaque anyway. How many **characters** is `ä` ? One or two?

Comment: that depends on the unicode encoding utf8, utf32 or whatever unicode encoding you use

Comment: @KaiIskratsch: It also depends on [the normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Multiple_Mark_Figure) --- NFD, NFC and such.

Comment: @KaiIskratsch: No, that's why I bolded **characters**. The encoding determines how many bytes each codepoint takes, but one glyph may take multiple codepoints. And some glyphs such as `ä` can be represented by multiple code point sequences of varying length. In particular, the same character can be precomposed or decomposed, one or two codepoints.

Comment: It likely works because the Unicode characters you feed your program don't have any NUL *bytes* in the stream.  Feed it a Unicode character that has a NUL byte in its multibyte value and your test program will likely truncate its output.

Comment: @MSalters: One better (or worse): one, two, or three codepoints --- which is the max for standard Unicode sequences, although more do appear in practice.

Comment: anyway you can always store them in a char array, the length of the needed char array is just hard to determine. and printf will stop priniting at the first 0 it encounters, and if its displayed corectly depends on teh output device

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Because of how UTF-8 works, what you're proposing is illegal UTF-8. A `0x00` is *always* NUL (this holds for everything in the range `0x00` to `0x7F` inclusive --- it's the same as ASCII). Multi-byte sequences (be it start or not) are always in the `>= 0x80` range. This is why many ancient C programs can just treat UTF-8 as any other encoding, and why C strings (being 0-terminated) still work!

Comment: @TimČas The question doesn't specify UTF-8 - that's only mentioned (currently, anyway) in the comments.  And I wasn't aware that there are no multipyte character sets with a NUL byte in any valid characters as I'm not familiar enough with the entirely of all multibyte character sets to know that, hence my comment about a multibyte character with a NUL byte as one of its bytes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Assuming OP is on a system with 8-bit `char` (which is not an unreasonable assumption), the question *strongly implied* UTF-8 --- or a variant such as UTF-EBCDIC (and I doubt it's the latter). Remember, he did say Unicode characters work.

Comment: @TimČas You're right, but he didn't say *which ones* worked so I didn't assume UTF-8, as the question doesn't provide the "working" data.  I was merely suggesting that he had picked values that just happened to work.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: He mentioned emoji working; AFAIK, no single-byte encodings (such as ISO-8859-1) support that. He also mentioned he uses Linux in a comment, and Linux uses UTF-8 nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works because the input and output stream have the same encoding, and you do not do anything with `c`.

Basically, you type something, which is converted into a sequence of bytes, which are then stored in `c`, then you send back that sequence of `bytes` to `stdout` which convert them back to readable characters.

As long as the encoding and decoding process are compatible, you will get the "expected" result.

Now, what happens if you try to use standard "string" C functions? Let's assume you typed "♠Hello" in your terminal, you will get the expected output but:

```
strlen(c) -> 8
c[0] -> Some strange character
c[3] -> H
```

You see? You may be able to store whatever you want in a `char` array, it does not mean you should. If you want to deal with extended character sets, use `wchar_t` instead.

Comment: My $0.02: `char` array is generally a *far* better idea than `wchar_t` array. `char` is guaranteed to be 8-bit in most relevant systems (so you can always at least store UTF-8 in it), but `wchar_t` varies from OS to OS. Furthermore, `wchar_t` is not guaranteed to be Unicode, either. And finally, per-character access is very, *very* rarely needed (and impossible to do directly even in UTF-32/32-bit `wchar_t`!).

Comment: @TimČas I don't disagree, I am not an expert, but if you use `char` you have to manually deal with encoding while `wchar_t` gives you some kind of abstraction. `wchar_t` may vary from OS to OS but its behavior seems more defined than `char` (I have the same behavior using `wchar_t` on my Linux and Windows, while `char` varies drastically between them).

Comment: @TimČas per character or per grapheme? technically utf-32 can do the former... just not the latter

Comment: @Mgetz: I don't think UTF-32 can do either. It can do code-points, but because of combining characters (which aren't really characters per-say), a single code-point is not necessarily a single *linguistic* character (which is what I meant --- nor is it a grapheme). The nomenclature is a bit messy, and ambiguous here, at any rate, so the distinction is a matter of semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running on Linux, with your terminal set to UTF-8 so `scanf` produces UTF-8, and `printf` can output it. UTF-8 is designed such that `char[]` can store it. I explicitly use `char[]` and not `char` because non-ASCII characters need more than one byte.

Comment: Well, `char[]` can store UTF-8 in any system, since it's (indirectly) guaranteed to be at least 8-bit. It might waste bits in some systems, though (e.g. certain DSPs with 32-bit `char`).

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, though? "..where char[] can store UTF-8" seems irrelevant as **all** `char`s can store UTF-8. The point is that apparently on OP's system, "ASCII characters, but [..] also [..] Unicode characters and emoji" are handled as UTF8.

Comment: @Jongware: I think a more accurate thing to say would be that in modern Linux, `char[]` *is expected to be* UTF-8 by the APIs. But it *can* be UTF-8 in any system (and indeed, more and more libraries are making that assumption --- converting to, say, UTF-16 for WinAPI as needed).

Answer (score 1):

Your program is undefined as it has undefined behavior.

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

expects a pointer to string, but

```
char *input[100];
```

`input` is pointer to pointer to `char`, `char *`.

Your program may work because the buffer you pass to scanf is of sufficient size to store unicode character and a characters you pass don't have a NULL byte in between them, but it may not work as well because the implementation of C on your (and any other) machine is allowed to do anything in cases of UB.

Comment: The OP said `It works as it should with ASCII characters, but it also works with unicode characters and emoji. why is this?`

Comment: It is of no importance because program is undefined

Comment: The example he gave is UB, but not the Question.

Comment: the outcome of the program, all the effects the run of it produces are undefined and of no importance. In fact the machine of OP's may stop to work now.

Comment: The whole point here could be more readable if the OP removes hes example. Isn't it ?

Comment: @tinky_winky *the outcome of the program, all the effects the run of it produces are undefined and of no importance*  That is totally irrelevant because in reality the `input` buffer in the program is 4 or 8 times larger than expected - while technically undefined, it has **nothing** to do with the question.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you, I just wanted to make this Question relevant which of course is different from the example he gave, but the Question was: `It works as it should with ASCII characters, but it also works with unicode characters and emoji. why is this?`

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: why is that? Michi's argument about focusing on Question is of no sense, as Question is about program with UB

Comment: @tinky_winky NO is not.  You could at least edit your Answer to answer to the OPs question and this will make your answer clear.

Comment: It could be only a type that `*`. The OP didn't responded on that. But hes Questions is still a question which i find it ok.

Comment: @tinky_winky: While it's important to recognise UB in the abstract and to be aware that it yields unpredictable practical results, we should not let that distract us from the broader conversation to the extent that we're summarily discarding any attempt to entertain said conversation. The bug with `scanf` usage here isn't particularly relevant to the crux of the question, which is that a string encoding sits on top of underlying byte representation, so UTF-8 can be "represented" by a `char` array just fine, just as it is also "represented" by a sequence of alternating electrical voltages.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the bug with scanf is extremely important to the crux of the question because question has no meaning when this bug is present - in other words, this bug explains everything